# suggest an inexpensive XPATH for the below code

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

The below is the sample selenium code. What will be efficient XPATH for this or a better regular expression which can be used

```
 @FindBy(xpath = ".//*[@id='Insurance_number' or @id='id_insurance_number_text' or @id = 'sInsuranceNumber']")
```

Comment: selenium doesn't support regex because it supports `xpath 1.0`, for better `xpath` solution  could you share HTML as well??

Comment: the html will be changed for every  product selected.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following variant:

```
@FindBy(xpath = ".//*[@id != ''][contains('Insurance_number;id_insurance_number_text;sInsuranceNumber', @id)]")
```

It is more concise, but I'm not sure if it yields better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your xpath with ".//*[ends-with(@id,'nsurance')]"

It assume it works for you.

Comment: It doesn't, because xpath is case-sensitive - it wouldn't catch `id_insurance_number_text`.

Comment: Agreed with ljedrz

Comment: ok..try ".//*[ends-with(@id,'nsurance')]"...updated my answer

Comment: That won't work either, the values end differently. E.g. `Insurance_number` ends with `number`.